# What is the best villager to get emeralds from?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am grinding emeralds to save up for some mending books from a librarian villager. However, it costs 38 emeralds (the most expensive price for an enchanted book), and I am having trouble getting emeralds to save up for them (~10 minutes per emerald). I have several novice villagers; I just set up my villager trading hall:

- Novice Weaponsmith: Default Novice trades
- Apprentice Toolsmith: 15 Coal for 1 Emerald, 1 Emerald for Stone Axe + Default Apprentice trades
- Novice Farmer: 20 Wheat for 1 Emerald, 1 Emerald for 6 Bread
- Novice Armorer: 15 Coal for 1 Emerald, 5 Emeralds for Iron Helmet
- Novice Librarian: 24 Paper for 1 Emerald, **38 Emerald + 1 book for 1 Mending book (target)**

Which villager should I farm-trade with, and if none of those are preferable, other villagers can be used as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Fletcher villager (with it's workplace block being the fletching table) that sells sticks for emeralds is a pretty decent and cheap trade. If you're able to make a dark oak, giant spruce, or giant jungle tree farm, or you just happen to have an over-abundance of wood, then this villager will prove to be very useful.

Comment: Turns out, that's exactly what I did! Do you think a fisherman or cleric villager would work as well?

Comment: I would imagine that they may not be as effective as fletchers, though if you have zombie or spider farms and have an excess of mob drops (as fishers often have string trades, and clerics have high chances of having rotten flesh trades), then fishers and clerics with those trades are still quite useful to have around.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use the Apprentice/Novice Stone Mason. They offer 1 emerald for 10 clay and also 1 emerald for 20 stone. It's a grind but worth it

Answer (score 2):

Clerics will trade Emeralds for Gold.

If you have a gold farm, this can be an efficient way to get Emeralds.

Answer (score 1):

Either novice farmer, considering wheat is pretty easy to get, or novice armorer, because coal is easy to get.

Comment: Okay... So I am wondering if you could put some more detail into that.

Answer (score 1):

Get a librarian that has emeralds-> bookshelves and books-> emeralds trades. Then, cure and infect it many times until the bookshelves cost one emerald and the books give one emerald. Then, get a book, trade for emerald, input emerald to get bookshelf, break bookshelf for 3 books, then repeat.

Answer (score 1):

if you are early in the game farmers with melon and pumpkin trades do a good job. just get a silk touch axe to mine the melons well. 4 melons to 1 emerald is a pretty good deal.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a beacon and efficiency IIIII pickaxe then you can trade different types of stone to stonemason ( work station is stonecutter ) . they buy all types of stone stone , clay , diorite , andrasite , granite and quartz . they will make you a awful lot of money and i would recommend infecting and curing the villager because it costs like nothing and your trades are exponentially cheaper

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A fletcher is good early-game, but will trap you into grinding wood and crafting sticks to get resources.

Later in the game, farmers are much better as they trade for pumpkins and melons, which can easily be farmed automatically. Farmers buy 6 pumpkins or 4 melons, which means curing them once will make them buy a single item for a single emerald.

If you want extremely large amounts of emeralds (e.g. for an emerald beacon), you can buy glass from librarians for one emerald, and sell glass panes to cartographers for one emerald. Be aware that this requires levelling up the librarians to level 3, and curing each cartographer at least twice.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to use a farmer(composter), though a fletcher(fletching table) is very useful as well.

Answer (score -1):

There is another great method but it needs multile curing of villagers.

You can buy glass from Librarians and sell glass panes to cartographers for a lot of emeralds.